# Jitter in map panning on Flutter iOS app when marker is added to google_maps_flutter instance

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

I have added google_maps_flutter to a Flutter app. When I add a single Marker to the map, then panning the map is jittery. If I remove the marker, then panning is smooth again. I am testing on an iPhone 14 Pro, and I have set xCode settings to Release mode.

Please note: When I keep my finger on the screen and move the map around, it is smooth. But when I swipe and release my finger so that the map panning animation continues after lifting my finger, then that is when the map is jittery.

Sample code, based on the example at https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'My App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  static const CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        // If I comment out the markers, the map pans fine
        markers: {
          const Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('marker_1'),
            position: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
          ),
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: const Text('To the lake!'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));
  }
}
```